# Python cx_freeze build error

Tags: python-3.x, module, runtime-error, executable, cx-freeze

I have recently wanted to make my python script executable via cx_freeze. I tried python 3.5 and 3.6 same error...

As error I get module.run() in stratup.py line 14 and in line 26 exec(code, m,**dict**)in console.py (both scripts belongs to cx_freeze).

It will be nice if someone will their working setup.py and some code they have used to build exe with no error (any code something not worthing i dont want to steal haha I just want to compare it with my code)

Any one know how to fix it or I have to do some extra import in my python script?

Answer (score 0):

My version of setup.py

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32' : base = 'Win32GUI'

opts = { 'include_files' : ['Pixel Skull.png'] , 'includes' : ['re'] }

setup(
name = 'Number generator' ,
version = '1.0' ,
description = 'Random number generator' ,
author = 'Silentstorm' ,
options = {'build_exe' : opts } ,
executables = [ Executable( 'Number generator.py' , base = base ) ] )
```

When you're done, put in the following lines in the command prompt:

```
python setup.py bdist_msi
```

I know you wanted a exe but this will generate a MSI which when you run the MSI, a exe file is made.
Hope it works for you. Also if possible can i get a copy of your setup.py?